# Running tests only found in test folder

Tags: phpunit

Here is my `phpunit.xml`:

```
<phpunit bootstrap="test/bootstrap.php"
         colors="true">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="MageScan Unit Tests">
            <directory>test</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

And my project structure

```
$ find src test -type f
src/bootstrap.php
src/MageScan/Application.php
src/MageScan/Command/Scan/Command.php
src/MageScan/Command/Scan/MagentoVersion.php
src/MageScan/PHPUnit/TestCase.php
test/bootstrap.php
test/MageScan/Command/Scan/MagentoVersionTest.php
```

When I run `phpunit` I get the error

> 1) Warning
>
> No tests found in class "MageScan\PHPUnit\TestCase".

Why is it looking for tests in this class?  Based on my testsuite configuration it should only be running tests in the `test` folder.

Comment: What if you run the test suite explicitly with `phpunit --testsuite="MageScan Unit Tests"`?